# Getting correct MIME type of a json file containing empty arrays

Tags: python, json, mime-types, python-magic

Using [python-magic](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/), I'm trying to guess the mime type of simple files and stumble upon this: if the json contains an empty array, the mime type returned is `'text/plain'` instead of `'application/json'`.

First, `import magic` and `from pathlib import Path`, then correct guess:

```
>>> content = {'entry': ['data']}
>>> Path('./config.json').write_text(json.dumps(content), encoding='UTF-8')
19
>>> magic.from_file('./config.json', mime=True)
'application/json'
>>>
```

Incorrect guess:

```
>>> content = {'entry': []}
>>> Path('./config.json').write_text(json.dumps(content), encoding='UTF-8')
13
>>> magic.from_file('./config.json', mime=True)
'text/plain'
>>>
```

Why is that so? Is it possible to have a consistent behaviour? Is it a bug in `python-magic`?

Note: I've explicitely added `encoding='UTF-8'` but it is useless, it's already the default encoding on my system (as shown by `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`).

Comment: Well unfortunately there may be no satisfying answer: see https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/issues/193 and https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic/issues/115

Comment: `libmagic` is heuristics-based; but more fundamentally, there's a large number of other guesses which would be equally correct for such a small fragment of data, and so returning the most generic type which is suitable seems like defensible and arguably correct behavior.

Comment: The bug reports you found simply say that there's noting in the Python wrapper which controls this behavior, and you should approach the maintainers of `libmagic` itself if you want this changed. The bugs are closed because the reporters are barking under the wrong tree, not because the maintainer of the Python wrapper disagrees. (But see my previous comment, too.)

Comment: @tripleee you're right, your comments may be the only answer to this question, actually!